# How to update ListView after updating database?

Tags: android, database, listview, updating

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Context context;
private DogDatabaseHelper dbHelper;
private ListView mListView;
private ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listforall);
    context = this;

    DogDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DogDatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select name from dog",null);
    int count = cursor.getColumnIndex("name");
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

        do{
            names.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        AdapterForNames namesAdapter = new AdapterForNames(this,names);
        namesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mListView.setAdapter(namesAdapter);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this,SetupActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("name",names.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the `ListView` I'm using, but after getting database updated, I can't get my `ListView` refreshed, I guess i should put some code in restart method?  But not sure what to do. Any help?

Comment: AdapterForNames namesAdapter = new AdapterForNames(this,names);
     
        mListView.setAdapter(namesAdapter);
 namesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
use adapter notify data set change after 
  mListView.setAdapter(namesAdapter);

Comment: Where do you add new records to the DB?

Comment: @param I've tried this,it didn't work.

Comment: @Ben please check the
  int count = cursor.getColumnIndex("name");
size by putting in log

Comment: @user13 When I clicked the names in the list view, all the information will be shown in the next activity and that's where i update my database

Comment: @param This is weird! Now it's 0, but i do remember that i get a number before,what should I do?

Comment: @Ben your table named dog is empty

Comment: @param But I checked,I do have data

Comment: @Ben please check the query because  int count = cursor.getColumnIndex("name"); returning 0 means no data is fetched

Comment: @param I found out that it's because i put that code in the wrong place,now  i can get data from database ,but still can't update the list view

Comment: check your names array size and if the size is grater than zero then check the code at  adapter side

Comment: @param Now i'm sure that there is something wrong with my adapter,because I don't know how to update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change following code:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Context context;
private DogDatabaseHelper dbHelper;
private ListView mListView;
private ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listforall);
    context = this;

    DogDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DogDatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select name from dog",null);
    int count = cursor.getColumnIndex("name");
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

        do{
            names.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        AdapterForNames namesAdapter = new AdapterForNames(this,names);
        namesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mListView.setAdapter(namesAdapter);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this,SetupActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("name",names.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

With below code:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Context context;
    private DogDatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private ListView mListView;
    private ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        context = this;
        AdapterForNames namesAdapter = new AdapterForNames(this,names);
        mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listforall);
        mListView.setAdapter(namesAdapter);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this,SetupActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("name",names.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        DogDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DogDatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select name from dog",null);
        int count = cursor.getColumnIndex("name");
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                names.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
                namesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just update your list with new data( ArrayList names ) and execute this code

```
namesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: did you got any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this wrong:

Calling below code in loop:

```
AdapterForNames namesAdapter = new AdapterForNames(this,names);
namesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mListView.setAdapter(namesAdapter);
```

Instead you should do below three tasks only once outside your loop:
1. create Adapter,
2. set it on listview,
 
3. setOnItemClickListener,
So move below two lines outside loop:

i.e.

```
AdapterForNames namesAdapter = new AdapterForNames(this,names);
mListView.setAdapter(namesAdapter);
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this,SetupActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("name",names.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

And inside loop you should call:

```
namesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

> **Note:** You only need to update the datasource after you set the Adapter on list, and notify the adapter that data is updated. Rest all
>   is one time process.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I must define adapter after getting the value of name parameter, so I can pass it: AdapterForNames namesAdapter = new AdapterForNames(this,names); hence I'm not sure I can call namesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); inside the loop where the adapter is not defined yet.

Comment: You have created ArrayList at class level, so just define Adapter defore do while loop, and inside do while loop update your data in list and call namesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Thanks for replying, I just tried, but unfortunately it still didn't work. Since I pressed back button, I'm thinking maybe should I do something in the onRestart method? Still no idea

Answer (score 0):

Register broadcast receiver like below

```
public class dbUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {    
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {    
            names.add("newly added name");
            namesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

```
  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("db_update_action");    
  registerReciever(new dbUpdateReceiver(), filter);
```

send this action whenever new record added like below

```
Intent intent=new Intent("db_update_action");
sendBroadCast(intent);
```